# calling language change through $translate causes "Broken interceptor detected: Config object not supplied in rejection": angular-loading-bar

Tags: angularjs, translate

The call to change the language using following method causes the error:

```
$translate.use(language);
```

The error in console:

```
angular.js:13294 SyntaxError: Unexpected string
at Object.parse (native)
at fromJson (http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1285:14)
at defaultHttpResponseTransform (http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10175:16)
at http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10266:12
at forEach (http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:321:20)
at transformData (http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10265:3)
at transformResponse (http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11054:21)
at processQueue (http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15627:28)
at http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15643:27
at Scope.$eval (http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16895:28)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:13294(anonymous function) @ angular.js:10007processQueue @ angular.js:15635(anonymous function) @ angular.js:15643Scope.$eval @ angular.js:16895Scope.$digest @ angular.js:16711Scope.$apply @ angular.js:17003done @ angular.js:11324completeRequest @ angular.js:11522requestLoaded @ angular.js:11463
2016-03-29 16:53:57.589 angular.js:13294 Broken interceptor detected: Config object not supplied in rejection:
```

Not sure what's wrong. Please let me know if anyone knows the solution.

Comment: seems like it's expecting a object in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out. The problem was in the localization string file, there was a comma missing after a newly added key-value pair. Silly mistake, but the error from angular was totally different.[image]

Comment: UNREAL. I looked for 4 hours for why my app was crapping out and it was because I put a comment, which VS2015 allowed, in the JSON file. Seeing your answer made me run it through a JSON validator and it caught it. I hate programming sometimes. I wish I could upvote you 20x.

Comment: @Yatrix, I remember I had wasted quite some time on this and posted the solution to help others like you once the moment I found out the issue. Glad that it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the sourcecode:

```
'responseError': function(rejection) {
    if (!rejection || !rejection.config) {
        $log.error('Broken interceptor detected: Config object not supplied in rejection:\n https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar/pull/50');
        return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
```

it will throw this error in the interceptor error handler, which probably means that you're doing a request that is failing. Could you open the network tab and have a look at what's happening when you switch languages? The problem should be visible there

Comment: Checked the network, only 1 GET call to the localization file with 200, OK status. No failed calls. Something is not being handled by the loading-bar related to localized resource access.